# How to store images in android other than sdcard and database

Tags: android, image

I am working on one android application,in that I have to download images from web and I am showing in listview using imageloader.Next time if I am not connected to internet I have to show saved images.So that If I want to save downloaded images where I have to store.I have two ways one way I have to store in sdcard and another one is in database.Is there any alternative way to store images.Image sizes are very small

Comment: Usually it not suggestible to store images directly into the database as blob but just a reference to retrieve them. Anyway, other than sdcard and database, you can always you the private application space, so in this way they users will only have the chance to manage the images through your app. Of course, with this solution and the database, if the user remove your app, also images will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Cache? Best way to do this:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Volley gives you a NetworkImageView, this is a "normal" ImageView, but you can give it a URL and volley will do all the rest for you (download, or load from cache, if already loaded).